# How do you keep track of total quantity from singular pack in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a couple in-app purchase items for hints for my iOS game. One pack is $0.99 for 6 hints, so if a user purchases this item, how do I keep a record of how many hints they have in total (given they keep purchasing and using)?  Could it be as simple as using Core Data?

Comment: Yes, you can use core data or the keychain.

Comment: Sweet, much appreciated, I figured it would be that obvious.